# Google closure compiler does some strange stuff with my js files

Tags: playframework, sbt, google-closure-compiler, playframework-2.2

I have written a small js script that will provide
a booking var for my other scripts.

**Small excerpt of script:**

```
var booking={
    venue: null,
    baseUrl: "http://fancy.url.com",
    align: "right",
    top: "200px",
    image: null,
    id: 0,
    height: null,
    width: "162px",
    action: "Boka",
    text: "Hello!",
    openStartpage: false,
    buttonColor: "green",

    // Variables
    imageUrl: "/assets/images/button/",    

    sayHelloToConsole: function (){
        console.log(hello);
    }
};
booking.init();
```

I load the script async with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _booking = _booking || {};
_booking["venue"] = "venue";
_booking["id"] = 3460483;
_booking["baseUrl"] = "http://localhost:9000";
_booking["buttonColor"] = "blue";

(function() {
function asyncLoad(){
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = 'http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/booking.min.js?v=1.0';
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad);
else
window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
})();
</script>
```

I let googleClosureComiler minify the script so that I can access the file in my play app. I have not provided any compiler options in my build.sbt file.

I then try to use the minified file the compiler has put in my public folder but
the compiler has done something very strange with the variables in the minified file.
E.g my variable is named booking$$module$booking instead of booking. So when
I want to access booking I get an error that booking is not defined. 
booking$$module$booking is defined and working.

Why did the compiler rename booking to booking$$module$booking? How do I prevent
this from happening?

Comment: It sounds like the build script is using the `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` and you probably want `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`. It also appears to be using the `debug` flag which causes property renaming to use $ symbols when flattening properties (so you can trace back errors). You should turn this off.

Comment: Oh thanks! Do you know how to do it or could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not with the play framework. I haven't used it.

Comment: Chad this could also be the CommonJS/RequireJS support option normalizing the modules.  Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah didn't think of that one.